# LVM LV path missing after wrong lvextend

Tags: lvm, thinpool

I'm a bit lost after an error I made in the command lvextend.

My setup:

- sda3 was only PV
- sdb added as empty disk
- have LV 'data' as LVM-Thin

My VG is "pve" and my LV is "data"

I did

```
# lvextend /dev/pve/data /dev/sdb1
```

While I should have done (I think)

```
# lvextend /dev/mapper/pve-data /dev/sdb1
```

Now the Path in "data" is missing when executing lvdisplay.

Output from

```
# lvs -o "lv_path,lv_dm_path,lv_kernel_minor"

Path                                       DMPath 
                                             /dev/mapper/pve-data                                    
  /dev/pve/root                              /dev/mapper/pve-root                                    
  /dev/pve/vm-100-disk-0                     /dev/mapper/pve-vm--100--disk--0
```

So, for pve-data the Path is missing as you can see.

fsck doesnt recognize the FS

```
# fsck -nv  /dev/pve/data 
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/pve-data
```

Can I reverse my first lvextend or fix it somehow?